# Euler's formula - Unique solution of second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given these conditions:

> $y”+y=0, \quad y(0)=2,\quad y′(0)=0$

and these observations:

> $y(x)=2\cos x$ and $y(x)=e^{ix}+e^{−ix}.$

How is it enough to conclude this?

> $2\cos x=e^{ix}+e^{−ix}.$

How can I be sure that a second-order differential equation with two constraints has a unique solution?

[Proof of Eular's formula](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-e-i%CE%B8-cos%CE%B8+isin%CE%B8/answer/Alexandre-Borovik)

Comment: What do you know about the transformation to first-order systems and the theorem of Picard-Lindelöf (-Cauchy-Lipschitz)?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sorry I actually know nothing about the things you mentioned above!

Comment: The question is, what level of answers do you expect? One could simply say that the ODE is smooth, so all solutions are unique. It is linear, so solutions exist and are defined as long as its coefficients are continuous. Here the coefficients are constant. You could consider $z=y'+iy$ to find that $z'=-y+iy'=iz$ and apply what you know about first order linear DE, provided you are comfortable with complex numbers.

Comment: As noted in the comment in the link, Euler took things ‘a step too far’.  It was roughly a century after Euler that Cauchy first seriously explored the issue of uniqueness, and the issue wasn't fully settled until the 20th century.

Answer (score 0):

Put $y=e^{mx}$, to get $m=\pm i$, this gives $y(x)=A e^{ix}+ B e^{ix}$. Next, $y(0)=2 y'(0)=0$ gives $A+B=2,A-B=0 \implies A=1=B.$ Finally, $y(x)=e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2 \cos x.$